# Align checkbox with a multi line label

Tags: html, css

See http://jsbin.com/ocutob/1/edit

```
<span>
  <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="1">
  <label>test test test test test test test test test test test test </label>
</span>
```

How can align the checkbox at the: top, bottom and middle?

I would do it with another container and using positioning, but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to use the [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) property on the `<label>` itself

http://jsbin.com/oloxes/1/edit (I specified a value of `top` in this example)

Comment: This works only if you can use a fixed width. It does not solve the problem in general.

Answer (score 8):

**Answer for 2015:**
Since `vertical-align` doesn't work for me (or not anymore), here's how I do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Radiobutton labels aligned</title>
<style type="text/css">
    div { display:table-row; }
    div span { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; } /* You can omit the entire span if you don't want the radiobutton vertically centered */
    div label { display:table-cell; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" id="a"></span>
    <label for="a">First button's label<br>First button's label</label>
</div>
<div>
    <span><input type="checkbox" id="b"></span>
    <label for="b">Second button's label</label>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="c"><label for="c">For comparison: Standard-Label</label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8jzss08p/
Works in: Firefox 41, Chrome 45, Internet Explorer 11